# Change Administrator Login in SQLAzure to new account

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

While experimenting, I created an initial administrative login for my first SQL Azure database.  Of course, now that I have familiarized myself with aspects of the portal interfaces I wish to use a better named account (changing password is easy).

How do I change the account listed in the portal to a new account without deleting the server (itself)?

NOTE:
I want to change the overall servers account.  Not an individual databases logins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the Administrator Account is not allowed in SQL Azure!

You will have to stick to the same name. However as you mentioned you can create multiple logins and users for each of the databases and use that account to manage the independent databases.